About ReorderableWrap bug
i am using ReorderableWrap for drag and drop function.
The error happen when i display 2 list of ReorderableWrap.
but it will be fine if i only using one of it
error
======== Exception caught by gesture library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while routing a pointer event:
Assertion failed: file:///Users/tanson/fvm/versions/3.10.6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/drag_target.dart:699:12
_candidateAvatars.contains(avatar) || _rejectedAvatars.contains(avatar)
is not true
the error sms :
====================================================================================================
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49      throw
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed
packages/flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart 699:82                              didLeave
packages/flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart 873:24                              [_leaveAllEntered]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart 885:5                               finishDrag
packages/flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart 794:5                               end
packages/flutter/src/gestures/multidrag.dart 156:13                               [_up]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/multidrag.dart 258:12                               [_handleEvent]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:12                           [_dispatch]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9                           
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13          forEach
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17                          [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7                           route
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 465:19                                 handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 445:14                                 dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 331:11                                dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 400:7                                  [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 363:5                                  handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 320:7                                  [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 293:9                                  [_handlePointerDataPacket]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1251:13                               invoke1
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 269:5                                 invokeOnPointerDataPacket
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 168:39                                    [_onPointerData]
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 791:20                                    
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 720:14                                    
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 317:16                                    loggedHandler
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall
my code as below :
Column(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            translate("lbl_product_list_page_information"),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize.toDouble()),
                          )),
                      _buildStringDataRow(translate("lbl_product_list_page_id"),
                          productIdController),
                      _buildStringDataRow(
                          translate("lbl_product_list_page_name"),
                          productNameController),
                      _buildImageDataRow(translate("lbl_product_image")),
                      _buildYoutubeDataRow(translate("lbl_product_video")),
                      if (showYoutube == true)
                        _buildAddYoutubeForm(
                            translate("lbl_product_youtube_url"),
                            youtubeController),
                      _buildStringDataRow(
                          translate("lbl_product_list_page_unit"),
                          productUnitController)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

Widget _buildImageDataRow(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
      child: Wrap(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "$title:",
                  style: primaryTextStyle(size: _fontSize),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ReorderableWrap(
              key: const ValueKey("Image"),
              needsLongPressDraggable: false,
              spacing: 5,
              runSpacing: 5,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                //unable to move the addMediaContainer
                if (oldIndex == imageList.length) {
                  return;
                } else {
                  if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex--;
                  final item = imageList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  //able image drag to end
                  if (newIndex == imageList.length - 1) {
                    imageList.insert(imageList.length, item);
                  } else {
                    imageList.insert(newIndex, item);
                  }
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
              children: <Widget>[
                for (int index = 0; index < imageList.length; index++)
                  _mediaWrapper(
                    index,
                    ProductMediaType.photo,
                    child: Container(
                      // key: ValueKey(image.media?.filename ?? ""),
                      key: ValueKey(imageList[index].id),
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      child:
                          Image.network(imageList[index].media?.mediaUrl ?? ""),
                    ),
                  ),
                if (imageList.length < 10)
                  Container(
                      key: const ValueKey("addImage"),
                      width: 80,
                      height: 80,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.add_a_photo,
                              size: 60,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            8.height,
                          ],
                        ),
                      )).onTap(() async {
                    final MediaLibraryModel? noteMediaMedia =
                        await const NoteMediaPicker(
                      availableTypeList: [
                        MediaType.photo,
                        MediaType.photoWeb,
                        MediaType.drawing,
                        MediaType.gif,
                      ],
                      aspectRatio: CropAspectRatios.ratio4_3,
                      cropLayerPainter: CustomEditorCropLayerPainter(),
                    ).launch(context);
                    onImagePick.call(noteMediaMedia);
                  })
              ])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildYoutubeDataRow(String title) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
      child: Wrap(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "$title:",
                  style: primaryTextStyle(size: _fontSize),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ReorderableWrap(
              key: const ValueKey("Video"),
              needsLongPressDraggable: false,
              spacing: 5,
              runSpacing: 5,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                //unable to move the addMediaContainer
                if (oldIndex == videoList.length) {
                  return;
                } else {
                  if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex--;
                  final item = videoList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  //able image drag to end
                  if (newIndex == videoList.length - 1) {
                    videoList.insert(videoList.length, item);
                  } else {
                    videoList.insert(newIndex, item);
                  }
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
              children: <Widget>[
                for (int index = 0; index < videoList.length; index++)
                  _mediaWrapper(
                    index,
                    ProductMediaType.youtube,
                    child: Container(
                        key: ValueKey(videoList[index].media!.mediaUrl),
                        height: 80,
                        width: 80,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        child:
                            _buildMediaView(context, videoList[index].media)),
                  ),
                if (videoList.length < 10)
                  Container(
                      key: const ValueKey("addVideo"),
                      width: 80,
                      height: 80,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_sharp),
                              iconSize: 70,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  showYoutube = !showYoutube;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
              ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

